# Странно работает самописный модуль в друпале

Tags: drupal, php

Здравствуйте. У меня почему-то некорректно работает модуль который использует API форм в друпал. Сами формы отображаются нормально, но при изменении настроек и авторизации пользователя друпал отображает белую страницу, которая пропадает после обновления.
Белый экран возникает при отправке данных из других форм,например при логине или сохранении конфигурации
Платформа : Drupal 6.20
Содержимое файла модуля:
    ﻿<?php

```
/**
 *@file
 *Шаблоны форм 
*/

/**
* Форма 
*/
function formchecklinks_page(){
$output =drupal_get_form('formchecklinks_nameform');
return $output;
}
function formchecklinks_nameform(){
$form['#method']='post';
$form['task_name']=array(
    '#title'=>t('Название задания'),
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#description'=>t('Поле для ввода имени задания'),
    '#size' => '30');
$form['email']=array(   
    '#title'=>t('Email'),
    '#type'=>'textfield',
    '#description'=>t('Пожалуйста, введите адрес вашей электронной почты'),
    '#size' => '30',
    '#default_value' => $user->mail,
    '#required'=>TRUE);

$form['file']=array(    
    '#title'=>t('Файл с заданием в формате CSV'),
    '#type'=>'file',
    '#description'=>t('Пожалуйста, выберите файл с заданием '),
    '#required'=>TRUE
    );
$pereodic = array(
 '0'=>t('Один раз'),
 '1'=>t('Каждый день'),
 '2'=>t('Раз в 2 дня'),
 '3'=>t('Раз в 3 дня'),
 '7'=>t('Раз в неделю'),
 );
$form['pereodic']=array(    
    '#title'=>t('Переодичность проверки'),
    '#type'=>'radios',
    '#description'=>t('Выберите переодичность проверки'),
    '#options'=>$pereodic,
    '#required'=>TRUE,
    '#default_value'=>'0'
    );

$form['submit']=array (
    '#value'=>t('Подтвердить'),
    '#type'=>'submit', 
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$output = drupal_get_form('**formchecklinks__index__nameform**');

function **formchecklinks_nameform**(){
..
}

Проверьте названия. Непонятно что имеется ввиду под " но при изменении настроек и авторизации пользователя друпал отображает белую страницу, которая пропадает после обновления." , можете пояснить?

Comment: Я дописал в топик пояснения по белому экрану и исправил код. Не помогло